# Does Internet Setting in control panel apply to InternetExplorer objects in other process?

Tags: .net, windows, internet-explorer

On windows applications can use IE engine by creating an InternetExplorer object and using it. Do Internet Settings in Control Panel apply to these objects?

Comment: Why not try it out?

Comment: I did. I disabled cross origin restriction but other applications still can't perform cross origin requests. Either something else is wrong, or InternetExplore objects don't respect these settings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no simple answer to this because it depends on the application hosting the browser control.

By default most options are shared but Internet Explorer opts into some features/settings by registering its application name under the [FeatureControls key](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537184(v=vs.85).aspx#sec_fck_registry). 3rd-party applications can also use these keys to opt in/out of certain features and security settings.

At run-time a hosting application can use the [`CoInternetSetFeatureEnabled` function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537168(v=vs.85).aspx) to set some options on the fly or they could implement [`GetOptionKeyPath`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa753258(v=vs.85).aspx) and/or `GetOverrideKeyPath` (IDocHostUIHandler2) to partially or fully override the users Internet Explorer registry settings.